# compare special column of each row with next row using bash

Tags: bash, text, compare

I have a text file that is arranged according to the first and second columns like this:

```
1 10
2 15
3 28
4 21
5 22
6 23
7 34
8 17
9 41
```

I want to compare  the second column of each row with next row, if it is larger, print it. if not , continue until find a row that second column is larger. output should be like this:

```
1 10
2 15
3 28
7 34
9 41
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '$2 > prev {print; prev = $2}'
```

Comment: Idiomatic way would be `$2 > prev{print; prev = $2}`

Comment: @123: I will edit my answer to simplify the syntax of my code, including your suggestion.